# Why does this not update my table in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server-2008, orm, sqlalchemy

I have the following code:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connectstring, echo=_echo).connect()
md = sqlalchemy.MetaData(engine)
table = sqlalchemy.Table('table_name', md, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
_Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = _Session()

for row in reader:
    table.insert({'key': 'value'})
session.commit()
```

Why does nothing get added to my table? The code runs, but the table is never updated.

Comment: What is `reader`? Is there anything in it?

Comment: It's an iterable with two entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the insertion was never executed.

```
table.insert({'key': 'value'}).execute()
```

fixes this problem.